# Get query string params in Sitecore and pass to a NextJS component

Tags: next.js, sitecore

I need to get the query string params for a Sitecore page and pass it to a NextJS component, on that page

I used this code:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
export default function MyComponent  (props: MyComponentProps) {
  const p = useRouter().query;
  console.log(p);
........

}
```

The output is an array with one element:

```
{
    "path": [
        "SitecorePage"
    ]
}
```

Alternately, if I try `window.location.href`, it breaks the page with a 500 error.

Any thoughts on how I could achieve this please?

Comment: Try using `asPath`, it should return the path as shown in the browser, see more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router#router-object